# Generate a dataframe sample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I want to create a sample dataframe.
As you can see there are 11 tasks. And special for `Task2`, `Task3` and `Task7` you have an option - so you can only choose on path.

I would like to create a sample dataframe with a start and end time for each task. How could I do that?
The important thing is that every the end should be in the future as the start. And the furhter task should be also in the future e.g. `Task2_Start > Task1_End` or `Task5_End > Task5_Start`. **Attention** Special Case you can go back from `Task8` to `Task7`. `So Task7_Start > Task8_End > Task8_Start > Task7_End`, because you can go back to `task7`.

How could I create a sample dataframe?

I want three columns (below you can find an example)

```py
d = {'id': [],
    'step': [],
     'timestamp': []}
```

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

steps = ['Task1', 'Task2', 'Task3', 'Task4', 'Task5', 'Task6', 'Task7', 'Task8', 'Task9', 'Task10', 'Task11']

num_ids = 10

data = []
for id in range(1, num_ids + 1):
    current_step = 'Task1'
    for _ in range(len(steps)):
        data.append({'id': id, 'step': current_step})
        if current_step == 'Task2':
            next_step = random.choice(['Task3', 'Task4'])
        elif current_step == 'Task7':
            next_step = random.choice(['Task8', 'Task9'])
        elif current_step == 'Task3':
            next_step = random.choice(['Task5', 'Task11'])
        else:
            next_step = random.choice(steps)
        current_step = next_step

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['timestamp'] = pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

---

Example with only three and without an condition

```py
import pandas as pd 
d = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'step': ['Task1_Start', 'Task1_End1', 'Task2_Start', 'Task2_End', 'Task3_Start', 'Task3_End',
              'Task1_Start', 'Task1_End1', 'Task2_Start', 'Task2_End', 'Task3_Start', 'Task3_End',],
     'timestamp': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-10', '2023-01-12', '2023-02-12', '2023-02-14',
               '2023-01-01', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-10', '2023-01-12', '2023-01-15', '2023-02-16',]}

df  = pd.DataFrame(data=d,)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but I think you may want to create a dictionary (`steps` in my code below) mapping each task to a list of possible next tasks.

Also, by storing each "timestamp" as a `datetime` object, you can add on a `timedelta` at each step -- here I've added on a random number of seconds between 30 and 60 at each step. That is, each "id" has a timestamp 30-60 seconds later than the previous.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random

steps = {
    1: [2],
    2: [3, 4],
    3: [5, 11],
    4: [5],
    5: [6],
    6: [7],
    7: [8,9],
    8: [7],
    9: [10],
    10: [1],
    11: [1]
}

num_ids = 100

records = []

current_task = 1
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
for _id in range(num_ids):
    records.append({
        'id': _id,
        'task': current_task,
        'timestamp': current_time
    })
    _possible_next_tasks: list = steps.get(current_task)
    current_task = random.choice(_possible_next_tasks)
    current_time = current_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=random.randint(30, 60))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
```

You could also define a dictionary mapping each task to how long the task takes, like

```py
times_dict = {
   1: (60, 120),
   2: (2, 5)
}
```

Then replace the replacement code inside the for loop with

```py
    _possible_next_tasks: list = steps.get(current_task)
    _secs_min, _secs_max = times_dict.get(current_task, (30, 60))
    current_task = random.choice(_possible_next_tasks)
    current_time = current_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=random.randint(_secs_min, _secs_max))
```

This will `get` the possible time range from `times_dict` and make a random choice of seconds from within that range, defaulting to (30, 60) if the current task isn't in `times_dict`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That sounds good. But is it also possible to create one `id` for completing the complete process? And every task should be a start and end e.g. `task1_start` and `task1_end`. Is this also possible? It should start by `1` and end by `11`.

Comment: Hi @Test, your diagram implies the process is continual, tasks 10 and 11 join to task 1. Do you mean the process should stop when it reaches task 11?